# How to find $V \cap W$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to find $V \cap W$ if:

$V = \text{span}( \{ (2,1,3,-1),(3,2,-1,2),(9,5,8,-1),(7,4,5,0) \} )$ and $W = \text{span}( \{(5,3,2,1),(6,4,-2,4),(1,1,-4,3),(4,2,6,-2) \})$.

Based on the given information, I've found the following basis of $V$ and $W$:

$B_V= \{ (2,1,3,-1),(3,2,-1,2) \} $ and $B_W= \{(5,3,2,1),(1,1,-4,3) \}$.

Because $V \cap W = \{x | x \in V \land x \in W \}$, vector $x$ can be written as:

$x= \alpha \cdot (2,1,3,-1) + \beta \cdot (3,2,-1,2) $ and
$x= \gamma\cdot (5,3,2,1) + \delta\cdot (1,1,-4,3) $.

Then we can write:
$ \alpha \cdot (2,1,3,-1) + \beta \cdot (3,2,-1,2) = \gamma\cdot (5,3,2,1) + \delta\cdot (1,1,-4,3)$ which yields in a system of four equations:

$$2 \alpha + 3 \beta = 5 \gamma + \delta $$
$$ \alpha + 2 \beta = 3 \gamma + \delta $$
$$ 3 \alpha - \beta = 2 \gamma - 4 \delta $$
$$ - \alpha + 2 \beta = \gamma + 3 \delta $$

Is this approach correct? Any hint to how to solve this system and in turn solve $V \cap W$?

Comment: Isn't "I've found the basis of V
 and W
:" supposed to mean "I've found the *following* basis of V
 and W:"?

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes, my wording isn't correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you did not find *the* bases of $V$ and of $W$. What you did find was *a* basis of each of those spaces.

And your approach is fine. But it's easier to see that$$(5,3,2,1)=(2,1,3,−1)+(3,2,−1,2)$$and that$$(1,1,−4,3)=-(2,1,3,−1)+(3,2,−1,2).$$Therefore, $W\subset V$. It follows from this and from the fact that $\dim V=\dim W=2$ that $V=W$. So, $V\cap W=V=W$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your approach is correct, and you can [solve your linear system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Solving_a_linear_system) for instance with [Gauss's algoritm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination), or by [successive substitutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Elimination_of_variables)  like this:
$$\begin{cases}2 \alpha + 3 \beta&= 5 \gamma + \delta\\\alpha + 2 \beta &= 3 \gamma + \delta\\3 \alpha - \beta& = 2 \gamma - 4 \delta\\- \alpha + 2 \beta &= \gamma + 3 \delta
\end{cases}$$
$$\iff\begin{cases}2(2 \beta-\gamma-3 \delta) + 3 \beta&= 5 \gamma + \delta\\(2 \beta-\gamma-3 \delta) + 2 \beta &= 3 \gamma + \delta\\3( 2 \beta-\gamma-3 \delta)- \beta& = 2 \gamma - 4 \delta\\\alpha&=2 \beta-\gamma-3 \delta
\end{cases}$$
$$\iff\begin{cases}\beta&=\gamma + \delta\\\alpha&=2 \beta-\gamma-3 \delta
\end{cases}$$
$$\iff\begin{cases}\beta&=\gamma + \delta\\\alpha&=\gamma-\delta,
\end{cases}$$
which means that $V\cap W=W.$